# How to use Durva grass in Shree Ganesha's puja?

Tags: ganesha, puja, festivals

I am preparing for Chaturthi this year, I would like to improve the puja to Shree Ganesha, I came to know that Ganesha likes Druva grass, but **I didn't know how to use it**.

I thought you were supposed to burn it like incense, but then I realized it was an erroneous belief, **I just realized it shouldn't be burned**.

**So how to use Durva Grass in Shree Ganesha puja?**

Thank you

Comment: Should not be burned .. it should be offered along with flowers or alone while saying Durvam samparpayami.

Comment: See the following links -- (https://www.astrojyoti.com/ganesha.htm) and (https://youtu.be/Ta8ylRCSbVQ)

Comment: @Rickross thanks a lot!